# HTML mail from POP3 account not rendering

Tags: gmail, html, pop3

I have an email address through Go Daddy and Gmail set up to access it via POP3.

When I receive an HTML email Gmail shows the headers (which normally isn't the case) and doesn't seem to be rendering it:

```
Reply-To: asf@asdf.com

Content-Type: text/html; boundary="PHP-alt-
c47a85530406b44b01ab6d38fac781d7"
Message-Id: <20110622173451.95BE6100A9@asdf.asdf.com>
Date: Wed, 22 Jun 2011 12:34:51 -0500 (CDT)

<html><body><p><b>Name: </b>Tommy</p><p><b>Email: </b>tom@yahoo.com</p>
   <p><b>Describe your issue or question: </b>adsfadf</p></body></html>
```

What might the reason for this be and is there a known fix?